# html button for fadeIn and FadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

Hey guys I'm making my own website just for fun and the following code makes a list of shapes appear. Does anyone know how I could incorporate another button instead of the fadeOut code to make it so that when I click another button, a "hide menu" button. The shapes will fadeOut. This is because the code I have at the moment means that the shapes will fade out by themselves over time. Pls help!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1aside").fadeIn(100);
    $("#div2aside").fadeIn(200);
    $("#div3aside").fadeIn(300);
    $("#div4aside").fadeIn(400);
    $("#div5aside").fadeIn(500);
    $("#div6aside").fadeIn(600);
    $("#div7aside").fadeIn(700);
    $("#div8aside").fadeIn(800);
    $("#div9aside").fadeIn(900);
    $("#div10aside").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#div11aside").fadeIn(1100);
    $("#div12aside").fadeIn(1200);
    $("#div13aside").fadeIn(1300);
    $("#div14aside").fadeIn(1400);
    $("#div15aside").fadeIn(1500);
    $("#div16aside").fadeIn(1600);
    $("#div17aside").fadeIn(1700);
    $("#div18aside").fadeIn(1800);
    $("#div1aside").fadeOut(17670);
    $("#div2aside").fadeOut(17660);
    $("#div3aside").fadeOut(17650);
    $("#div4aside").fadeOut(17640);
    $("#div5aside").fadeOut(17630);
    $("#div6aside").fadeOut(17620);
    $("#div7aside").fadeOut(17610);
    $("#div8aside").fadeOut(17600);
    $("#div9aside").fadeOut(17590);
    $("#div10aside").fadeOut(17580);
    $("#div11aside").fadeOut(17570);
    $("#div12aside").fadeOut(17560);
    $("#div13aside").fadeOut(17550);
    $("#div14aside").fadeOut(17540);
    $("#div15aside").fadeOut(17530);
    $("#div16aside").fadeOut(17520);
    $("#div17aside").fadeOut(17510);
    $("#div18aside").fadeOut(17500);
    $("section").fadeOut(0);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You mean like chain fadeOuts? When one finish another start so on?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, you should do a toggle, I find this the simpliest way to do that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var toggle = 0;
   $("button").click(function(){
      if (toggle === 0) {
       $("#yourDivsToFadeIn").fadeIn(YourTimeToFadeIn);
       toggle = 1;
      }
      else if (toggle === 1) {
       $("#yourDivsToFadeOut").fadeOut(YourTimeToFadeOut);
       toggle = 0;
      }
   });
});
```

EDIT: You also could use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
       $("#YourDivsIds").fadeToggle(YourTimeToToggleTheFade);
    });
});
```

But I find the first way to do this better, because if you get to learn some more Javascript/jQuery, there arent always .toggle methods to toggle something. Then you better should learn - and get used to -  the first method.
-But thats just my point of the view.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need two buttons in your HTML:

```
<button id="infader">Fade all in</button>
<button id="outfader">Fade all out</button>
```

Then in your JS you first select all divs to fade with one jQuery selector and store them in a variable. It's faster, less to write and the attachment of the different fading times becomes easier.

```
// get all divs with an ID that ends with 'aside'
var asides = $("div[id$='aside']");

// get first button and attach the click-handler
$("#infader").click(function() {
    // take all asides and use 'each() to execute a function on each of them
    // keyword 'this' is one div-element, i is it's index in the collection
    asides.each(function(i) {
        // the divs gets a fading time depending on their index
        // the first (i == 0) gets 100ms, the last (i == 17) gets 1800ms
        $(this).stop().fadeIn((i + 1) * 100);
    });
});
// get second button similar
$("#outfader").click(function() {
    asides.each(function(i) {
        $(this).stop().fadeOut((17 - i) * 10 + 17500);
    });
});
```

What does the `.stop()` before `fade`? Lets say you have started a fadeIn and then click the out-button before it has completed. Now the fadeIn ist stopped and the fadeOut begins immediately. If you want instead the fadeIn finishing completely before fadeOut runs just remove the `.stop()`.
Its easy to change the fade-times to fit your needs.